# How can I remove a word and a comma which I don't know where it is?

Tags: java, string, replace

Such as

```
String  str = "Tom,Jerry,Brady,Patriots,TempaBay";
```

I want to remove one of the word in one function. .What I want to do is replace "Tom," or ",Jerry" in one line of code.vBut the position of comma is different. Is there an regular expression can use?

I try to write the codes like this.

```
str = str.replace("Tom","");
//then the result is ",Jerry,Brady,Patriots,TempaBay"
//I have to write another line of code
str = str.substring(1);
//It's Jerry turn
str = str.replace("Jerry","");
str.substring(1);
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how to remove a word and its leading/trailing comma (if there is one)?

Comment: Apparently, it could be trailing coma if the first word, leading comma if the last word, and either comma if an "in-between" word.

Comment: Sorry ,I didn't make the question clear.What I want to do is replace "Tom,"  or ",Jerry" in one line of code.But the position of comma is different.Is there an regular expression can use?

Comment: What have you tried? Please see the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You may edit the question to include that information. While you are at it, I suggest changing the title.  One possibility is "Looking for Regex to replace or remove, from a String, a word and its delimiter."

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestion.I go to the right way with your help after my first question in StackOverFlow.I value this.Thank you so much.

Comment: If the string is `Tom` alone (so no comma, neither before nor after), do you want the empty string as result? Or something else?

Comment: You may use `str.replaceFirst("Tom,|,Tom|Tom", "")`. This turns `Tom,Jerry,Brady` into `Jerry,Brady`, `Brady,Tom,Jerry` into `Brady,Jerry`, `Jerry,Brady,Tom`  into `Jerry,Brady` and `Tom` alone into the empty string. Assuming that the name to remove can change, build the string `Tom,|,Tom|Tom` from `name + ",|," + name + "|" + name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt the other folks here will have a much better and simpler way of accomplishing this, but one way that is fairly basic, easy to modify, and doesn't require you to know regex/Java Streams is something like this:

```
    String  str = "Tom,Jerry,Brady,Patriots,TempaBay";
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));  // split the string into pieces based on the , character
    list.remove("Tom");  // remove your target string from the array, if it exists at all
    str = String.join(",", list);  // re-join the remaining elements of the array using the , character
```

I don't think this will be the most performant option available to you, so depending on your use case, it may or may not be appropriate, but hopefully it at least makes sense.

Comment: That works.I think your solution is the K.I.S.S way like in Unix.That's good.Thank you!

Comment: It’s a good solution IMHO. The string represents a list, so processing it as a list makes everything clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll` with a regular expression to match the word followed by a comma, with a special case for the last word where we would have to remove a leading comma.

```java
var word = Pattern.quote("Tom"); // in case there are special characters
str = str.replaceAll("," + word + "$|\\b" + word + ",", "");
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5NC8IwDL37K0LxsGHdD1AU9CgIgt7UQ9yqdLZrSetkqL99Zk7E5JCP9/JeSqxxXBbXtvW3k9E55AZDgDXqCh4D4PjuQ8TIpXa6AMtoso2kq8v@CEiXkH7JXfQAHxDMQOyclStF1MglYdHIDTLsYpA7ZT0usRHT3@XZESQ1EtwdFTDpJLLgjY6JkCJNf7yPSxOispm7xcyzXzRVIkhZVysQMOoVRtyO55@5kyLlDeZqYUyn90caPg@H0/9CcrJh/9lr8GrbNw)

Comment: I will try it by using Java.I will learn how to use regular expression.Thank you!